# mediaplayer how to stop playing

Tags: android

I am playing some wav file and after while i want to stop it.

I am using singleton like

```
private static playSound instance = null;

public static synchronized playSound getInstance(Context context) {
    if(null == instance) {
        instance = new playSound(context, "", 1);
    }

    return instance;
}
```

and i am calling

```
public void stopAudio() {
    try{
        myplayer.stop();
        myplayer.release();         
    } catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught:\n" + e.getMessage() +"\n" + e.getStackTrace());               
    }
}
```

`instance` is not null so i think this should work because is the same instance...

but i get:

```
MediaPlayer: stop called in state 1
```

Comment: check if the mediaplayer is playing before you attempt to stop. you can use isPlaying() method to check that. if the player is in idle state and you are trying to stop it you might get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check first is it playing or not ?? If it is playing your stop method should work.

E.g :

```
if (   media_player             != null
    && media_player.isPlaying() == true) {
    try {
        media_player.stop();
        media_player.release()
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```